# Handle udefined or null in child component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent and a child component. Say

```
Parent{
    render(){
       return(
          <Child1 />
          <Child2 list={this.state.value}/>
       )
    }
}
```

Now my problem is my when my control reaches Child2,props.list will always come null and when my i will click my selectbox from Child1 then state will get populated and hence list in child2.

The problem that i am facing is when the control first reaches child2 the console in browser shows list is not defined and it breaks and nothing is being rendered in my child1.How to handle this scenerio?

Also

is there a way that i can put some condition on child2 that if state is loaded only then it should be rendered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is throwing the error that `props.list` is `null` then you need to handle this case inside Child2 component by putting the check on the value of `this.props.list`. Like this:

```
class Child2 extends React.Component{

   render(){
       console.log(this.props.list)
       if(this.props.list)
           return <div>
                {this.props.list}
                /*other code*/
           </div>
       return null;
   }

}
```

If Child2 contains proper list value then only `render` the complete component.

Or if you want to `render` something instead of `null` then replace the `null` part by some other component:

```
class Child2 extends React.Component{

   render(){
       console.log(this.props.list)
       if(this.props.list)
           return <div>
                {this.props.list}
                /*other code*/
           </div>
       return <div>No content</div>
   }

}
```

Comment: oh i was doing a very silly mistake!was returning nothing in else condition and so the flow was breaking.Thanks:)

Comment: sometimes that happens, glad it helped to solve your issue :)