# Passing object in props after fetching from API, reactjs with typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I fetch data from API and I want to pass it in *HotelCard* component as props.

```
export default function HotelPage() {
  const [hotelInfo, setHotelInfo] = useState<object | null>(null);
  const params = useParams();
  const id = params.id;

  async function fetchHotelById() {
    const result = await HotelsService.fetchById(id);
    setHotelInfo({
        name: result.name,
        description: result.summary.tagline,
        location: {
            address: result.addressLine,
            city: result.city,
            countryCode: result.countryCode
        },
        images: result.images,
        review: result.reviewInfo.value
    });
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchHotelById();
  }, [id])

  return (
    <>
      <HotelCard info={hotelInfo}/> //here info is underlined
    </>
  )
}
```

The issue with info:

> Type '{ info: object | null; }' is not assignable to type
> 'IntrinsicAttributes & hotelInfoProps'.   Property 'info' does not
> exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & hotelInfoProps'.

HotelCard.tsx

```
export default function HotelCard({ info }: hotelInfoProps) {
  return (
    <section className='hotel__card'>{info.name}</section>
  )
}
```

The issue is:

> Property 'info' does not exist on type 'hotelInfoProps'

And hotelInfoProps:

```
export type hotelInfoProps = {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    location: {
        address: string;
        city: string;
        countryCode: string;
    };
    images: object [];
    review: string;
}
```

I cannot figure out how to solve this issue with info and what causes the problem.

Comment: You would need to declare a member: `info: object | null` in your hotelInfoProps type.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44373250/handle-udefined-or-null-in-child-component-in-reactjs

Comment: @YogeshKumarGupta, your comment is partially correct, because the `hotelInfoProps` type should match the shape of the `hotelInfo` object that is passed as a prop. However, this is not the main problem, because the error message is about the info prop, not the hotelInfoProps type. The main problem is that the HotelCard component expects a prop named info, but it is not declared in the hotelInfoProps type. To fix this, you can either rename the prop to `info`, or add a property named info to the `hotelInfoProps` type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for all your answers and help, it really helped me a lot. What worked for me was adding additional type:

```
export type hotelInfo = {
    name: string;
    description: string;
    location: {
        address: string;
        city: string;
        countryCode: string;
    };
    images: object [];
    review: string;
}

export type hotelInfoProps = {
    info: hotelInfo | null;
    
}
```

and:

```
const [hotelInfo, setHotelInfo] = useState<hotelInfo | null>(null);
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the `hotelInfoProps` incorrectly, because you are not using the proper syntax for typing props in React. You can try this:

You can try this:

```
export default function HotelCard(info: hotelInfoProps) {
  return (
    <section className='hotel__card'>{info.name}</section>
  )
}
```

But it is not the recommended way to type props in React. You should use the `React.FC` (or `React.FunctionComponent`) type to declare your functional component, and pass the props type as a generic parameter. For example:

```
const HotelCard: React.FC<hotelInfoProps> = ({ name }) => {
  return <section className="hotel__card">{ name }</section>;
};

export default HotelCard;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your object hotelInfo is initialized as null before fetching the data from you API but you pass this object to your HotelCard component that expects to have a non nullable object. You should either put a condition to render the component only if hotelInfo is not null or update HotelCard to also handle a null object.

Comment: This is a good point, and it is important to handle the null case for hotelInfo. However, this does not address the TypeScript error that the OP is asking about. I explained this in more detail in my answer.

Comment: You're right, I first saw the null issue without making any link with the error message, thanks for you answer aswell !